# blast tab limited out extraction

Tags: sorting, awk, blast

I  have blast result like this..

```
GCA_001188035.1_1       GCA_001188035.1_1       100.00  159     0       0       1       159     1       159     8e-113   324
GCA_001188035.1_1       GCF_000878595.1_1595    100.00  159     0       0       1       159     853     1011    2e-104   327
GCA_001188035.1_1       GCA_001267965.1_78      100.00  159     0       0       1       159     853     1011    2e-104   327
```

i want to extract above result based on 3 rd column (<=90) using awk. please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$3<90' File
```

If `3rd` column less than `90`, print the line.

Comment: define "not working" pls... error msg? too slow? or what? @user3295716

Comment: while running comment  a error message shows like  '"killed'"